# On Rust, is it possible to alloc a slice of memory, in such a way that the returned pointer fits in a u32?

Tags: rust

[HVM](https://github.com/kindelia/hvm) is a functional runtime which represents pointers as 32-bit values. Its allocator reserves a huge (4 GB) buffer preemptively, which it uses to create internal objects. This is not ideal. Instead, I'd like to use the system allocator, but that's not possible, since it returns 64-bit pointers, which may be larger than the space available to store them. Is there any cross-platform way in Rust to allocate a buffer, such that the pointer to the buffer is guaranteed to fit in an `u32`? In other words, I'm looking for something akin to:

```
let ptr = Box::new_with_small_ptr(size);
assert!(ptr as u64 + size < u32::MAX);
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to? Avoiding the system allocator is probably quite beneficial to performance. And even if you could get the allocator to return 32-bit pointers, Rust only supports a single pointer size.

Comment: Note that due to memory overcommit, allocating 4GB doesn't take up any memory until you actually try to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, because it's an extremely niche need and requires a lot of care.

It's not as simple as "just returning a low pointer" - you need to actually allocate that space from the OS. Your entry point into that would be [`mmap`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Be prepared to do some low-level work with `MAP_FIXED` and reading `/proc/self/maps`, and also implementing an allocator on top of the memory region you get from mmap.

If your concern is just excess memory usage, note that Linux overcommits memory by default - allocating 4GB of memory won't reserve physical memory unless you actually try to use it all.